# Chef: access values from nested hash

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, erb

I have the following array in my recipe

```
 users = {
   'User1': {'car': 'auto1', 'number': NumGenerator.generate},  
   'User2': {'car': 'auto2', 'number': NumGenerator.generate}
}
```

And my template erb file is

```
<%= @car %>
```

I want to generate a file with the name of the user - for example "User1" and I want to add the value of the variable "car" - auto1 - to the template. How can I achieve this? It would be great if the order of the values doesn`t matter.

```
template '/etc/mytest/User1.txt' do
  source 'mytest.conf.erb'
  variables(car: users['User1']['car'])
end
```

Even

```
 variables(car: users[0][1])
```

is not working. I always get the error message "undefined method [] for nil.NilClass"

Comment: Despite quotes, `'User1':` makes key _a symbol_. So either change colons in the declaration to hashrockets everywhere (`'User1' => ...`) or use `users[:User1][:car]`.

Comment: @Aleksei I'll try it after the weekend. Which solution of the two should be used preferentially?

Comment: They are equivalent, pick any you like more.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin It`s working. I`ve one further question: when I want to add "User1" to the variables how should I specify this? variables ('username': users[:User1]) and variables( username: users['User1'] is not working

Comment: I have no idea about `chef` in general, and the last question seems to be `chef`-specific. Sorry about that.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin if I understand you correctly, this is not possible with pure ruby?

Comment: `variables` function is `chef`-related, right? You are asking how to properly call it, right? What do you expect to be possible with pure [tag:ruby] here then?

Comment: I thought that accessing the items of the array is ruby-related. But I will simply add another "name" item to the array